# Filling Modal when opened using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, html

Im calling a Modal and want it to be filled dinamically when it gets opened. I've tried using append but it didnt work.

This is my Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalForAllUsers" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Meine Reservationen</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <table class="table justify-content-center table-bordered " style="text-align:center;">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">FillME</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how im calling it

```
 <a id="BtnGetUsers"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalForAllUsers">
 <i style="color:blue;" class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </a>
```

And this is how ive been trying to fill it

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BtnGetUsers").click(function () {
            $('#ModalForAllUsers').on('show.bs.modal');
            $(".cell").prepend("<td>Test</td>");
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "didn't work". It works fine when I tested your code (if prepend is what you intend to do)

Comment: Otherwise, $(".cell").text("Test"); https://jsfiddle.net/7bwL9noq/

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen for me the "Fillme" text just stays and test is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Check my fiddle. prepend() adds element to the front, so if you want to replace FILLME with Test, use text()

Comment: yeah ive tried that. Didnt work either

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? "Test" is not showing inside $('.cell'), then it's something else. Check how I use text() in my fiddle without <td></td>

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave the button the id `BtnGetUsers`. That is why the function is not called

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BtnGetUsers").click(function () {
            $('#ModalForAllUsers').on('show.bs.modal');
            $(".cell").prepend("<td>Test</td>");
           
            })
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalForAllUsers" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Meine Reservationen</h5>
                <button type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <table class="table justify-content-center table-bordered " style="text-align:center;">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">FillME</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



 <a id="BtnGetUsers"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalForAllUsers">
 <i style="color:blue;" class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </a>
```

Comment: Apologies, i missed the a element. It wasn't having any text. Add some text to it and it will be visible. click on it and test will show

Comment: sorry what? The <i> font awesome should also work as a link. The modal opens, the "test just doesnt get displayed"

Comment: try now. Added the font awesome library too. It will be clear now

Comment: maybe because the btn is in a foreach in my code. Ill figure it out somehow. Thanks

Comment: If there is some other error poat the code here. Will try to help

Answer (score 0):

Worked like this without the data-target attribute and filling the modal before opening it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnGetUsers').click(function () {
            $(".cell").text("Test");
            $('#ModalForAllUsers').modal('show')
        });
    });
</script>
```